# Casting string time to timestamp for calculation of date time difference?

Tags: javascript

I have data coming from an API which formats what should be a datetime object as a string. So the format is: "2021-04-22 19:32:00".

I have a start date and end date in this format.

Since it's a string, using JavaScript to pull out the hours isn't challenging, but I'm wondering, now that I have my two string variables of a theoretical begin and end time, how do I calculate how difference in these two parameters.

Meaning:

object 1 start time would be : "18:30:00".
object 2 end time would be : "20:00:00".

And I want to know that difference is 90 minutes...

Comment: What have you tried so far and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

for this to work in safari you need to add a T to the middle to create a valid date

```js
console.log(new Date("2021-04-22 19:32:00".replace(/ /,"T")))
```